# Any experience with turtl? unable to remove it

Tags: package-management

I've this thing installed here appearing as 'Turtl' under office category of items. 
Have no idea what it does, unable to remove it, unable to open/start it.
Even synaptic doesn't show much -

[image]

[image]

Comment: turtl is an evernote-like app.  It's not available in repos, Ubuntu or PPA - you would have had to have manually installed it.  The process to remove it is generally the opposite of the steps you followed to install it in the first place.  I can't tell what DE you are using, but see if you can right click on the menu entry to find the path of the application.  See: https://turtlapp.com/

Comment: @Nmath nopes, it doesn't give any info on right clicking or hovering over it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `turtl` [is installed with](https://github.com/turtl/desktop/blob/master/README.md) `npm` if that's how you installed it, that's how you uninstall it.
`npm uninstall turtl`

Sources:
https://github.com/turtl/desktop/blob/master/README.md

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall

Comment: you are on the right track man...but it seems i've messed up some of the files . Unable to uninstall:      `navjeet@navjeet-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ npm uninstall turtl
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/navjeet/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/navjeet/package.json'
npm WARN navjeet No description
npm WARN navjeet No repository field.
npm WARN navjeet No README data`

Comment: @EetSandhu Perhaps this will help you resolve that related issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866494/how-do-you-reinstall-an-apps-dependencies-using-npm or perhaps this https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-reinstall